# How do I run VLOOKUPS and calculations in a single formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's my issue!

Step 1 - VLOOKUP based on criteria from raw data
Step 2 - VLOOKUP that returned value from another set of data to return a new value

The complications I have are 1) VLOOKUPS won't work with a formula in the cell and 2) I don't want to have to run 2 separate VLOOKUPS to get the final value I want.

Is there a way I can build this into a single formula? Or possibly a VBA script?

Cheers guys!

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample data AND describe the end result you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using MATCH() and INDEX()

Suppose your first table has 3 rows and 2 columns and is in the range A1:B3.

Your second table has 3 rows and 2 columns and is in the range E1:F3.

**Step 1**

```
=INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH("Raw data",A1:A3))
```

**Step 2**

If step 1 was done in cell H1 then you can use the result from that to look up a value in the second table

```
=INDEX(F1:F3,MATCH(H1,E1:E3))
```

**A single formula**

You can put these together in a single formula

```
=INDEX(F1:F3,MATCH(INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH(A12,A1:A3)),E1:E3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the nested vlookup function though. See the picture below ;)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDQH0.png)